# Having an issue with Firestore rules

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[image]

[image]

Having an issue setting some rules in Firestore. So basically the creatorId is in the document, and I don't understand what is going on with the rules. I hardcoded the id in the rules and it works if I do `request.auth.uid == 'iv4Lk1148KVBkney3eFdNZPWMC43'; it works.

I really don't how to fix this.

```
match /jobApplications/{applicationId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.creatorId;
    allow write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

I am building a Flutter app and this is the method responsible for grabbing the data from `jobApplications`. It's part of an infinite scroll list.

```
void _loadMoreApplications() async {
  final CollectionReference applicationsRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('jobApplications');

  Query query = applicationsRef.limit(25);

  if (lastDocument != null) {
    query = query.startAfterDocument(lastDocument!);
    setState(() {
      isLoadingMoreApplications = true;
    });
  }

  try {
    final applicationDocs = await query.get();
    if (applicationDocs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      lastDocument = applicationDocs.docs.last;

      Set<ApplicationModel> uniqueApplications = applications.toSet();

      for (var doc in applicationDocs.docs) {
        uniqueApplications.add(ApplicationModel.fromFirestore(doc));
      }

      applications = uniqueApplications.toList();

      setState(() {
        showSpinner = false;
      });
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoadingMoreApplications = false;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error fetching applications: $error');
  }
}
```

The print from the catch:

> flutter: Error fetching applications: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: You should also show what you are doing to trigger that error.  The code itself isn't enough - we need to see what steps you take to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi Doug. I was trying to show that the data is correctly set in the database and what is happening when I use the Sandbox. I will add the code that is requesting the data. Thank you!

Comment: If you're doing something in the simulator (reading or writing a document) to cause the error, that's what we need to see.  We should be able to reproduce the result using the information you provide.  The rules themselves don't mean anything until they are combined with some access to the underlying data.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what I'm doing wrong ... since I hardcoded the value and the app retrieved the data. once I add `resource.data.creatorId;`, I get the error I mentioned in my edit.

Comment: That's because your app is trying to access documents where the rule is being violated.  Frank's answer is correct - security rules do not filter documents for you - your application query filter must match the constraints of the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have missed the documentation section that explains that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), but rather they just check that the code doesn't request more data than it's allowed to.

Your code requests the documents from all users, while the rules explicitly say that it can only request documents from the current user. Since the code is requesting more documents than allowed, the rules reject the operation.

To meet the requirement of your rules, the code should only request documents for the current user, so with an additional `where` condition on `creatorId`.

Also check out these other [questions about rules not being filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5d%20rules%20are%20not%20filters&searchOn=3) as this is a quite common mistake.

Comment: Wow ... Nice! Thank you. I really didn't know that.